# java DuplicateKeyException has already been caught

Tags: java

I am working with HashMap and am attempting to generate a DuplicateKeyException to prevent overwriting existing keys.

I am trying to throw this exception based on certain user input but am receiving an exception has already been caught error.

```
try {
  Student student = map.get(uid); // uid is a user defined input.
  if (student != null) { // test for key existence
    key = true;
  } else {
    key = false;
  }
  if (key = true) { // throw duplicate key exception
    throw new DuplicateKeyException();
  } else { // Put new uid into map
    map.put(uid, new Student(name, major));
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It worked...");
} catch (NullPointerException z) { // If the key doesn't exist
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That record does not exist.");
} catch (DuplicateKeyException x) { // If the key does exist
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That record already exists.");
} catch (NumberFormatException y) { // If user input is other than expected
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter integer.");
}
```

NullPointerException and NumberFormatException are working as expected until DuplicateKeyException is implemented.

"catch DuplicateKeyException()" shows "exception DuplicateKeyException has already been caught."

I have attempted to modify exception order in case they were too broad.  That didn't seem to help the issue.

I'm still new to this and any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (key = true) {...` => `if (key) {...`

Comment: You probably meant `if (key == true)`, but @pzaenger is correct, you should just write `if (key)`. Also, the previous `if` statement can be just `key = (student != null);`.

Comment: @pzaenger - thanks for the tip...

Comment: @Andreas thanks a lot